# How to set focus in tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

have spent a while looking for an answer. I'm new to Python but not to coding in general. Finding the various versions quite challenging!

Anyway I'm very Gui orientated and have managed to get tkinter working with Python 3.5.1

Just playing with basics and have the following code but cannot set focus to the first entry box. Have tried mEntry1.focus() and mEntry1.focus_set() but always get object has no attribute error. Any help?

```
from tkinter import *

def calc(*args):
  try:
      value1 = float(V1.get())
      value2 = float(V2.get())
      result.set(value1 * value2)
  except ValueError:
    pass
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('450x450+200+200')
mGui.title('Test Gui')
V1 = StringVar()
V2 = StringVar()
result = StringVar()
mEntry1 = Entry(textvariable=V1,width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
mEntry2 = Entry(textvariable=V2).grid(row=1,column=0)
mButton = Button(text='Calculate',command=calc).grid(row=3,column=0)
mlabel = Label(textvariable=result).grid(row=4,column=2)
```

Comment: And what happens when you try `mEntry`.focus_set()`? The result you get will tell you the problem.

Comment: One of the strong features of Python are the trackbacks and error messages.  Learn to understand and use them. I presume you got "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'focus_set'".  That means that mEntry is the singleton None, not an Entry, like you must have thought.  You also need to know that the default return for calls is None.  So when the help for .grid says "Position a widget ..." and never says what it returns, assume None.  This is normal for pure side-effect calls.

Answer (score 2):

Every Tkinter widget has the `focus_set` method.

The problem with your code is that the `.grid` method returns `None`. Thus

```
mEntry1 = Entry(textvariable=V1,width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
```

sets `mEntry1` to `None`, not the widget. So you need to create the widget and put it in the grid in two steps:

```
mEntry1 = Entry(textvariable=V1,width=10)
mEntry1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
```

Of course, if you don't actually *need* a reference to the widget object then it's ok to do it in one step. So something like

```
Entry(textvariable=V1,width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
```

would be fine.

---

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `from tkinter import *`. It imports over 130 names into your namespace, which can lead to name collisions with your own names, or with those of other modules if you also import them with a "star" import statement. It also makes the code harder to read. Instead, you can do

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then refer to Tkinter names using the `tk.` prefix, eg `tk.Entry` instead of `Entry`.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, great explanation. I've spent the last 3 years programming Filemaker and am finding this a bit of an uphill slog in comparison!

Comment: (cont) Yes, it can be a bit difficult to get your head around it at first, but if you keep playing with small test programs of your own, and modifying the numerous good examples here on SO (and elsewhere online), I'm sure you'll gradually become comfortable with it.